# change one droplist data depending on other selected droplist item

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

i have 2 drop down lists and DB in my web application project. in the DB i have domain table and subDomain table. in the subDomain table i have foreign key to the column DomainId in domain table.
i populate the 1st droplist with data from domain (im using DomainId as datavalue and DomainName as datatext/ here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ToString();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DomainId , DomainName FROM Domain",conn);
        conn.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DomainName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DomainId";
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }
```

now when the user select item from the droplist i want to populate the 2nd droplist according to the item that was selected, but its not working.
here is the 2nd part of code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleConnectionString"].ToString();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);



        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SubDomainName, SubDomainId FROM SubDomain where DomainId= @id", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        conn.Open();
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "SubDomainName";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "SubDomainId";
        DropDownList2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        conn.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoPostBack property of your DropDownList1 control to true. If you already set that, but still have an error, post your .aspx file also